# C# how to run a method in the background? (use Task.Start not Async/Await)

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

Here's the UI code.   Attempting to compute disk usage for files and folders displayed in listview.

```
                if (FileHelper.IsFolder(info))
                {
                    UsageSummary usage = DiskUsage.GetTotalUsage(info.FullName).Result;
                    totalSize += usage.TotalSize;
                }
                else
                {
                    totalSize += info.Length;
                }
```

Here is the GetTotalUsage() method.   The idea is that it should return a cached value if available.  If the value is not available it will return the size of just the files at the top level and launch another method that will recursively descend the directory tree from that point and creating cache entries, so that the next time we visit the folder we should get a cached value.

```
  async public static Task<UsageSummary> GetTotalUsage(string folder)
  {
    UsageSummary totalUsage = null;

    if (!IsCached(folder, ref totalUsage))
    {
        // Not cached, get first-level usage
        totalUsage = GetFileUsage(folder);

        // Start async process to cache total usage of this folder
        await AsyncCacheUsage(totalUsage);

    }

    // Was cached, or we got the first-level results.
    return totalUsage;
}
```

The final method is the gateway method to the recursive functions that compute the real size of the folder.

```
   async private static Task AsyncCacheUsage(UsageSummary summary)
    {
        try
        {
            AccumulateChildFolders(summary.Folder, summary);

            CacheResults(summary);

            // Now we start a watch on the volume that 
            // can invalidate cache entries when changes occur.
            _watcher.WatchVolume(summary.Folder);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "CacheTotalUsage: {1}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The code seems to work and behaves as expected in the debugger.

But my question is, am I doing this right?  The GetTotalUsage method is going to be called once for each subfolder in the folder being displayed many instances of AsynchCacheUsage outstanding all descending different branches of the filesystem.  Which means I need to start worrying about thread safety?  All the code is static, including access to a static dictionary that caches the usages which I should probably add a lock to.   Any other pitfalls I'm missing?

It seems weird that I am calling "await AsyncCacheUsage"  when I really mean go off and do your work and don't bother me.

Comment: I think you should be getting a warning for `AsyncCacheUsage`. Are you, and are you choosing to ignore it?

Comment: Nothing in `AsyncCacheUsage is doing an `await` therefore it will block its thread. Likely `AccumulateChildFolders` should be async as well, but you need to be careful updating an object passed as a parameter (I assume you update the `summary` parameter with results) as this will be updated *after* the function has returned. Better to use a return value.

Comment: Doesn't the  asynchrony begin above in GetTotalUsage.?   That's where I intend for it to begin.  I'm not getting the "your method will run synchronously" warning from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems weird that I am calling "await AsyncCacheUsage" when I really mean go off and do your work and don't bother me.

That's not what the posted code will do. It will run `AsyncCacheUsage` synchronously (since there are no `await`s - as Damien noted, the compiler is giving you a warning that `AsyncCacheUsage` will run synchronously). Then it will `await`, which will never actually yield control.

The code you posted simplifies to this:

```
// No async, since there's no await
private static void AsyncCacheUsage(UsageSummary summary)
{
  try
  {
    AccumulateChildFolders(summary.Folder, summary);
    CacheResults(summary);
    _watcher.WatchVolume(summary.Folder);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Log.Error(ex, "CacheTotalUsage: {1}", ex.Message);
  }
}

// No async, since there's no awaits
public static UsageSummary GetTotalUsage(string folder)
{
  UsageSummary totalUsage = null;
  if (!IsCached(folder, ref totalUsage))
  {
    totalUsage = GetFileUsage(folder);
    AsyncCacheUsage(totalUsage); // No await anymore
  }
  return totalUsage;
}

if (FileHelper.IsFolder(info))
{
  UsageSummary usage = DiskUsage.GetTotalUsage(info.FullName);
  totalSize += usage.TotalSize;
}
else
{
  totalSize += info.Length;
}
```

In other words, there's nothing actually asynchronous in any of the code you posted.

> But my question is, am I doing this right? The GetTotalUsage method is going to be called once for each subfolder in the folder being displayed many instances of AsynchCacheUsage outstanding all descending different branches of the filesystem.

That's not what the posted code does. It always executes synchronously, one folder at a time, all on the calling thread.

That's probably just fine. Most disk devices don't take kindly to dozens or hundreds of simultaneous requests spread across the device.

That said, if you *do* want to make this asynchronous, you should start with your lowest-level API calls - whatever you're calling to get the disk usage of a directory (presumably within `AccumulateChildFolders`). Once that's asynchronous, then you can let the `async` grow from there. At some point (probably still within `AccumulateChildFolders`), you can use `await Task.WhenAll` to process multiple folders concurrently (again, if you want).

Comment: There is an await in the first procedure.   That's where Intend for the asynchrony to begin.  Perhaps it's the name that's throwing you off.   AsyncCacheUsage can block as much as it wants.  The intent is that the GetTotal usage should return the cached result or the  first level-approximation.   And let the cache building proc grind away. I used it a process because it really is a heavy wait [sic] task that I want to fire and forget.

Comment: I think you might be confused about what `async` does. Without an `await`, it won't be asynchronous. As I stated, the compiler will give you a warning when you use `async` without `await` because it is almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: Right.  I made the warning go away, but I still wasn't quite doing what I thought.  I knew it could be right to await for something I didn't want to wait for.  I obeyed the warning and converted to Task/Start.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is no.  I'm not doing it right.   The await suspend the execution of the calling method and returns the task object to the call object to original caller.   When the the awaited operation completes the async method resumes it's execution.   The original caller can synchronize with the asynchronous procedure by invoking the Result method on the Task object that the async method returns.   I'm not wanting to wait for anything.  I just want to start a background task.

So my code should look like this:

On UI thread:

```
                if (FileHelper.IsFolder(info))
                {
                    totalSize += DiskUsage.GetTotalUsage(info.FullName)
                }
                else
                {
                    totalSize += info.Length;
                }
```

The GetTotalUsage method returns the cached result or a the first-level approximation and starts a task that will populate the cache.

```
  public static long GetTotalUsage(string folder)
  {
    UsageSummary usage = null;

    if (!IsCached(folder, ref usage))
    {
        // Not cached, get first-level usage
        usage = GetFileUsage(folder);

        try
            {
                // Start task to FillCache for this folder.
                Log.Info("Start FillCache: {0}", folder);
                var cacheTask = new Task(() => FillCache(usage), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                cacheTask.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DuLog.Error(ex, "!!! Run cacheTask: {0}", ex.Message);
            }

    }

    // Was cached, or we got the first-level results.
    // Race condition. FillCache() is updating usage.TotalSize.
    return usage.TotalSize;
}
```

FillCache calls AccumulateChildFolders (recursive) with the first-level total and caches the final result.   Intermediate results are cached along the way.

```
   private static Void FillCache(UsageSummary usage)
    {
        try
        {
            AccumulateChildFolders(summary.Folder, summary);

            CacheResults(summary);

            // Now we start a watch on the volume that 
            // can invalidate cache entries when changes occur.
            _watcher.WatchVolume(summary.Folder);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "CacheTotalUsage: {1}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `new Task` and `Task.Start` should never be used. Your older code (using `Task.Run`) was better.